# Is it possible to set up constraints in subclass of UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, constraints

```
class SpecialButton: UIButton {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I want to create a custom button subclass of a UIButton. I want to set up constraints of this button. In view controller, I can use `view.addSubview()` method and set up `button.topAnchor.constraint` there, but it does not work in this subclass. How can I approach it? Or am I trying to approaching it in a wrong way? I am new to coding, please let me know.

This is the code after I put a super view property in the class. I think it works and solve my problem. Is there any better solution just let me know.

```
    class SpecialButton: UIButton {

    let superView: UIView

    init(superView: UIView) {
        self.superView = superView
        super.init(frame: .zero)

        superView.addSubview(self)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be the same... post the code of the view controller

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: I do not want to set up constraints in view controller to make it clean. Is it possible?

Comment: I put a new code block in the question, is this a good solution for adding constraints in subclasses?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add a constraint involving the button's top anchor until the button is part of the view hierarchy, that is, until it has a superview. The button knows when it has been added to a superview because it receives `didMoveToSuperview`. That is the earliest moment you could put your constraint code.

Comment: oh, I see now. Thanks a lot. Is there a way to put the potential super view into the button subclass?

Comment: I put a new code block in the question, is this a good solution for adding constraints in subclasses?

Comment: The button's superview, from the button's perspective, is `self.superview`.